# Appending hex values to a list/converting string lists to hex

Tags: python, hex, can-bus

I have a dataframe where each row is a CAN message which has to be in hex. But when I put the rows into a list, individual values are stored as strings. For example:

`['0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x1']`

Is there a way to have `[0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1]` instead?

Comment: So you want to retain the objects type? Can you post the `type()` of the object?

Comment: Python represents hex literals as their denary values, for example `[0x01, 0x02]` as `[1, 2]` so you have to choose between strings or normal integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy enough! Use the [base](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) parameter on the `int` function to convert from hex string to integer, and you can use [hex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) to go back from integer to hex string.

```
# Convert hex string to int
str_vals = ['0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x1']
int_vals = [int(val, 16) for val in str_vals]
```

```
# Convert int to hex string
int_vals = [0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1]
str_vals = [hex(val) for val in int_vals]
```